# Android, Cast View to TextView throw Exception

Tags: android, casting

I trying to cast a viewObject to `TextView` object with this code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) GetViewWithParams(Object);
```

The function "GetViewWithParams" returns viewObject.
But when I run it I got this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot cast view to widget. check my answer!

Comment: `I trying to cast a viewObject to textView ... How can I fix it?` You **can't**: you are trying to do something which is **not allowed**.

Comment: Why? the class TextView extends View..

Comment: please provide the GetViewWithParams function

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
```

Comment: In function "GetViewWithParams" I create programmatically a new view, then I retrun it. So I have no id.

Comment: paste your "GetViewWithParams"